# Regular expression, replace multiple slashes with only one

Tags: php, preg-replace

It seems like an easy problem to solve, but It's not as easy as it seems. I have this string in PHP:

```
////%postname%/
```

This is a URL and I never want more than one slash in a row. I never want to remove the slashes completely.

This is how it should look like:

```
/%postname%/
```

Because the structure could look different I need a clever preg replace regexp, I think. It need to work with URLS like this:

```
////%postname%//mytest/test///testing
```

which should be converted to this:

```
/%postname%/mytest/test/testing
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$str = preg_replace('~/+~', '/', $str);
```

Or:

```
$str = preg_replace('~//+~', '/', $str);
```

Or even:

```
$str = preg_replace('~/{2,}~', '/', $str);
```

A simple `str_replace()` will also do the trick (if there are no more than two consecutive slashes):

```
$str = str_replace('//', '/', $str);
```

Comment: Much shorter than expected. I could not make it fail. Thanks!

Comment: str_replace won't do like this. you need a recursive function I believe. (take a look below)

Comment: As Gal says, the str_replace won't work if there are more than two slashes. The preg_replace will work but Bart K's version is better because it doesn't match single slashes, just two or more

Comment: @meouw: Thanks, I was in doubt with that one - fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Late but all these methods will remove `http://` slashes too, but this.

```
function to_single_slashes($input) {
    return preg_replace('~(^|[^:])//+~', '\\1/', $input);
}

# out: http://localhost/lorem-ipsum/123/456/
print to_single_slashes('http:///////localhost////lorem-ipsum/123/////456/');
```

Comment: so helpful. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', '////%postname%//mytest/test///testing');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function drop_multiple_slashes($str)
{
  if(strpos($str,'//')!==false)
  {
     return drop_multiple_slashes(str_replace('//','/',$str));
  }
  return $str;
}
```

that's using str_replace

Comment: That won't work unless you change _!== 0_ to _!== false_. Plus, there's no need for recursion: _while (strpos($str, '//') !== false) { $str = str_replace('//', '/', $str); } return $str;_

Comment: @GZipp, you're right, I edited it. As far as I know, there is no difference in performance between recursive function and while loop (but I could gladly be proven otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
while (strlen($uri) > 1 && $uri[0] === '/' && $uri[1] === '/') {
    $uri = substr($uri, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do $str = str_replace('//', '/', $str, $count); while($count);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo str_replace('//', '/', $str);
```

Comment: No, that will replace `'////'` with `'//'` while a single slash is needed here.