# How can I remove escape characters using PHP?

Tags: php, escaping

I have the following text

```
$text = "\\vct=140\\AraignÃ©e du soir espoir,araignÃ©e du matin,espoir du matin."
```

I want to remove the escape characters using php..I do not want to use stripslashes since it is server dependent..

I want to remove the '\' before the '\vct=140' and the '\' before '\Arai....' 
How can I remove them from the string?

Comment: What kind of escape characters in that string do you want to remove?

Comment: I want to remove the '\' before the '\vct=140' and the '\' before '\\Arai....'

Comment: How is `stripslashes` server dependent? [Why](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal) are you removing the slashes? This question suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Outis Just jhave a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php ,the Note section..

Comment: I'd look if only I understood French.

Comment: `"\\vct"` actually means the string `\vct` (slash escapes slash in literals, yadayada). So you simply want to remove the single remaining slash, i.e. simply remove any backslash from the string...?!

Comment: @user954687 I browsed the notes you linked and I see no reference on what you say about it being "server dependent"...What's your goal here, btw?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217759/regular-expression-replace-multiple-slashes-with-only-one

Comment: I have a Server whose magic quotes settings is OFF.So, the stripslashes does not work for me.Any other solution apart from stripslashes?

Comment: @user954687 you're a a bit confused on what magic_quotes is

Comment: @user954687: [magic quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) have no affect on `stripslashes`. When magic quotes are enabled, data from [certain sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) is first passed through the equivalent of `addslashes`. You still need to state your overall goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell `stripslashes` works [as per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
<?php
$string = '\\\\vct=140\\\\AraignÃ©e du soir espoir.';
echo $string, "\n";
echo stripslashes($string), "\n";
```

Which outputs:

```
\\vct=140\\AraignÃ©e du soir espoir.
\vct=140\AraignÃ©e du soir espoir.
```

Sequence `\\` is in list of [escape sequences for special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) so you got to escape slashes twice.