# How can I replace a blackslash character?

Tags: php, string, escaping, str-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I removing escape characters using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749690/how-can-i-removing-escape-characters-using-php)

I have a string having two backslash characters.

```
 $str1 = '\\audio=mix=\"SixAM/SixAM_Daddysugar/DADDY_COOL.PCM\"\\ \\spd=144\\Araignée du soir espoir,araignée du matin,espoir du matin.text';
```

I want to replace `\\` to `\`.
I want to use `str_replace` php function.
Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You actually don't have to do anything to "replace '\' to '\'" cuz it's allready replaced..

Comment: Use the manual or beginner howtos from the WWW. This is more an Q&A Board, not an "make my homework"-place, as the orange bar at the top which had already informed you about this. Here a good starting point for your use-case: [str_replace()](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Replacing \ to \ doesnt even makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered using [stripslashes()](http://bg.php.net/stripslashes) ?

Comment: -1 You asked the same 1h ago and was answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749690/how-can-i-removing-escape-characters-using-php

Comment: You simply refuse for some wrong standpoint to use stripslashes(), which here does the trick well; the answer you was given works and it's perfectly reasonable, you just have confusion on how it works so are looking for any other possibile solution (though @Tenerif one is good too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a backslash you have to escape it with another backslash. So in your example to replace `\\` you have to escape each of them with backslash, so you can try this

```
$replaced = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $str1);
```